# Rrrepeattt keyys in Ubuntu 14.04 driving me nuts

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, cinnamon

**Problem:**

Repeat keys while typing, unless I use an extraordinarily slow and careful touch on the keyboard.  (Example:  Thhe quickk browwn fox.)

**System:**

Dell Precision 7710 with Ubuntu 14.04 and Cinnamon 2.85 desktop, although I've often seen the problem in Unity

**Troubleshooting tried to date:**

(1) System settings --> Keyboard --> change 'Repeat delay' to the highest available 'long' setting, and 'Repeat speed' to the slowest available setting.  I now have 'Enable Key Repeat' turned off entirely.

(2) `sudo kbdrate -r 2 -d 1000` from the command line

The BIOS doesn't have a 'typematic' setting.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**update:**

I just spent almost an hour typing with an external keyboard attached via the USB port, and didn't get double keys once. -- May I safely assume that the problem is with the Precision 7710's relationship with the OS, and not with the OS itself?

Answer (score -3):

Try running these commands in terminal:

Method 1:

```
 sudo su
 apt update
 apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 apt install unity
 reboot
```

Method 2:

```
sudo su
rm -rf ~/.config
```

Method 3:

```
sudo rm -rf .compiz-1
```

Hope it works.

Comment: Why should this fix it? Also, you made a few misspells in the answer.

Comment: It is because problems in system settings is usually caused by system corruption and above steps does a fresh install of ubuntu desktop removing all corruption. Here the problem is with software properties and in this way the problem will be resolved.

Comment: If even that doesn't work then there is a simple command, sudo rm -rf .compiz-1. That's it.

Comment: `apt` won't work here, the OP has 14.04, this would requier `apt` to be installed, use `apt-get` on anything but 16.04 questions.

Comment: This seems to be more of a last-resort solution.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, one and all.  I'll admit that I had hoped for a more modest solution: a setting change in a configuration file, perhaps, or some other step that would save me from reinstalling the desktop.

Comment: Your settings itself are corrupted and the only way out is to reinstall them

Comment: Please give any better solution if known, otherwise explain the downvoting

Comment: At least using this method fresh installation won't be required, files will be preserved and apllications will not get uninstalled. Only the desktop is getting refreshed much like in windows 10 where windows store apps are not uninstalled and data is preserved. Needless to say that the whole process will take much much less time rather than a complete reinstallation

Comment: First, I'll note that I genuinely appreciate your time to respond.  I mean it!  I'm a stranger to you, and you're still taking time to try to help me with this issue.  -- I could bow out silently, but want to be candid.  I'm not as knowledgeable about ubuntu as you, am leery of making things worse ... particularly as the problem is in Cinnamon, and not in the almost-never-used Unity.   -- What I _might_ do: prepare for a complete new install, perhaps with Mint 18, and then try this just before loading the Mint 18 DVD.  I'll have nothing to lose then.  -- In the meantime, I'll wait.

Comment: @Timoteo I'd suggest trying Xubuntu or Kubuntu instead of Mint. Or if you really like Cinnamon then install it on an Ubuntu install.

Comment: @Timoteo Mint is developed upon ubuntu and it gets it software from officiaal ubuntu repositories. But Ubuntu has lots more features like more frequent updates, canonical partner repositories and lots of other supported repositories which are not there in Mint. So what you are basically going to do is downgrading is OS. Moreover in Ubuntu too you can ditch unity and get cinnamon

Comment: This thread is now ten days old, and may have dropped off the AskUbuntu radar, but I can post an update:  I just spent almost an hour typing with an external keyboard attached via the USB port, and didn't get double keys once. -- May I safely assume that the problem is with the Precision 7710's relationship with the OS, and _not_ with the OS itself?

Comment: @Timoteo Just change the keyboard settings of the os to the one built for the built in hardware. Every keyboard comes with a built in settings, for example eng-US-international, en-GreatBritain and so on. change the keyboard settings of your OS to the one that is built in your keyboard hardware. Regarding how to please do some googling, otherwise I will post a reply two days later

Comment: and do consider upvoting me